# Como somar strings de números

Tags: python-2.7

Bem eu tenho uma string do género a=("1234") e eu queria separar esses números de forma a somá-los, assim: 1+2+3+4 
Como consigo fazer isso? Agradeço qualquer ajuda :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, caso a string contenha apenas números:

```
sum([int(x) for x in a])
```

Essa linha cria uma lista com os caracteres da string convertidos para número e depois soma cada elemento da lista.

Lembrando que isso não verifica se a string só contém números e soma cada posição da string, por exemplo, se eu tiver "1234" o resultado dessa soma será 10.

## EDIT

Como você disse que não pode utilizar a compressão de lista, outra forma possível é verificar elemento a elemento dentro de um `for` e fazer essa soma, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
soma = 0
minha_string = "123456"
for numero in minha_string:
    soma += int(numero)
```

Isso terá o mesmo efeito (e mesmas restrições) da compressão de lista.

Comment: Nesse caso você está a utilizar um mecanismo de listas em compreensão?

Comment: será que não me consegue dar outro exemplo mas sem usar esse método? peço desculpa pelo incómodo

Comment: Com bibliotecas nativas do python, acredito que essa seja a melhor forma... Algum problema em usar compreensão de listas? .__.

Comment: é que no trabalho que eu preciso de fazer não posso usar compreensão de listas :/

Comment: @CrisRomina, atualizei com outra forma, poderia verificar se ela te satisfaz?

Comment: Yes!! thank you for helping me!:)

Comment: @CrisRomina Se a resposta lhe ajudou você pode aceitá-la e votar não só nela mas em qualquer outra coisa que achar útil no site. Veja o [tour].